# Let SourceViewerDecorationSupport use different preference store for CharacterPairMatcher

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my eclipse plugin I implemented my custom editor that extends `TextEditor`.

I need the editor (or rather it's `SourceViewerDecorationSupport`) to use the default preference store in order to provide the annotation markers eclipse creates but I also want to have a `CharacterPairMatcher` to work on it but this does only work (as far as I can see) via the `setCharacterPairMatcher(matcher);` and `setMatchingCharacterPainterPreferenceKeys(...)` methods of the `SourceViewerDecorationSupport`.
The problem is that the preferences used for the matcher are in a different preference store...

Is it possible to tell the `SourceViewerDecorationSupport` to look in another preference store for the keys specified for the `CharacterPairMatcher`?
And if not how can I "transfer" the preferences from the default preference store to my own one?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but looking at the source the preference store specified on the `install` call is used for everything.

Comment: Hm then I've got a problem because I'd need it to work on two seperate preference stores...

Comment: Some plugins implement their own `IPreferenceStore` which delegates to multiple different stores.

Comment: Yepp that could be an idea...Have to look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As greg suggested the solution was to create a custom `PreferenceStore` that can combine multiple `PreferenceStores`.

For anyone having a similar issue, here is how I solved it:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert;
import org.eclipse.jface.preference.IPreferenceStore;
import org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceStore;
import org.eclipse.jface.util.IPropertyChangeListener;

/**
 * A preferenceStore that allows to combine multiple preferenceStores
 * 
 * @author Raven
 *
 */
public class MultiPreferenceStore extends PreferenceStore {

    /**
     * A list of all preferenceStores that should be combined
     */
    List<IPreferenceStore> stores;

    /**
     * Creates an instance of this preferenceStore
     * 
     * @param store
     *            The base store to start with
     */
    public MultiPreferenceStore(IPreferenceStore store) {
        Assert.isNotNull(store);

        stores = new ArrayList<IPreferenceStore>(2);

        stores.add(store);
    }

    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(IPropertyChangeListener listener) {
        for (IPreferenceStore currentStore : stores) {
            currentStore.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(String name) {
        for (IPreferenceStore currentStore : stores) {
            if (currentStore.contains(name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void firePropertyChangeEvent(String name, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        for (IPreferenceStore currentStore : stores) {
            currentStore.firePropertyChangeEvent(name, oldValue, newValue);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the respective preferenceStore that contains the given
     * preference (It will return the first store that matches a preference with
     * the given name)
     * 
     * @param name
     *            The name of the preference to search for
     * @return The respective preferenceStore or the first one when the name
     *         could not be matched by any of the stores
     */
    private IPreferenceStore getStoreContaining(String name) {
        for (IPreferenceStore currentStore : stores) {
            if (currentStore.contains(name)) {
                return currentStore;
            }
        }

        // return the first one in order to avoid NullPointerExceptions
        return stores.get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBoolean(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getBoolean(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getDefaultBoolean(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getDefaultBoolean(name);
    }

    @Override
    public double getDefaultDouble(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getDefaultDouble(name);
    }

    @Override
    public float getDefaultFloat(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getDefaultFloat(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDefaultInt(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getDefaultInt(name);
    }

    @Override
    public long getDefaultLong(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getDefaultLong(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultString(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getDefaultString(name);
    }

    @Override
    public double getDouble(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getDouble(name);
    }

    @Override
    public float getFloat(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getFloat(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int getInt(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getInt(name);
    }

    @Override
    public long getLong(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getLong(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).getString(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDefault(String name) {
        return getStoreContaining(name).isDefault(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean needsSaving() {
        for (IPreferenceStore currentStore : stores) {
            if (currentStore.needsSaving()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void putValue(String name, String value) {
        // put in base store
        stores.get(0).putValue(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(IPropertyChangeListener listener) {
        for (IPreferenceStore currentStore : stores) {
            currentStore.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setDefault(String name, double value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setDefault(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDefault(String name, float value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setDefault(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDefault(String name, int value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setDefault(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDefault(String name, long value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setDefault(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDefault(String name, String defaultObject) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setDefault(name, defaultObject);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDefault(String name, boolean value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setDefault(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setToDefault(String name) {
        getStoreContaining(name).setToDefault(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String name, double value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setValue(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String name, float value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setValue(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String name, int value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setValue(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String name, long value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setValue(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String name, String value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setValue(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String name, boolean value) {
        // add to the base store
        stores.get(0).setValue(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void save() throws IOException {
        super.save();

        for (IPreferenceStore currentStore : stores) {
            if (currentStore instanceof PreferenceStore) {
                ((PreferenceStore) currentStore).save();
            } else {
                try {
                    // see if there is a save method and if yes try to invoke it
                    Method saveMethod = currentStore.getClass().getMethod("save",
                            (Class<?>[]) null);

                    saveMethod.invoke(currentStore, (Object[]) null);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException
                        | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // can't save
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given <code>IPreferenceStore</code> to this store if it is not
     * already contained
     * 
     * @param store
     *            The store to add
     */
    public void addPreferenceStore(IPreferenceStore store) {
        if (!stores.contains(store)) {
            stores.add(store);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the given <code>IPreferenceStore</code> from this store
     * 
     * @param store
     *            The store to remove
     */
    public void removePreferenceStore(IPreferenceStore store) {
        stores.remove(store);
    }
}
```